# Find $\sqrt[m]{\frac{\sqrt[m]{\frac{\sqrt[m]{\frac{\sqrt[m]{a}}{a}}}{a}}}{\begin{array}{c} a\\\vdots \end{array}}}$

Tags: contest-math, nested-radicals

> Assuming $m\in \Bbb N\setminus\{0,1\}$ and $a\in \Bbb R_+\setminus\{0\}$, find 
>   $$\sqrt[m]{\frac{\sqrt[m]{\frac{\sqrt[m]{\frac{\sqrt[m]{a}}{a}}}{a}}}{\begin{array}{c}
> a\\\vdots
> \end{array}}}$$

In a book I'm studying the author gives $$a^{\frac{m}{m+1}}$$ as the answer. But I'm a little uncomfortable with the development presented. In an example, in which $a=128$ and $m=6$, the numeric result given is 64 (by applying the formula).

But, trying to compute a numerical evaluation of the sequence, it appears to converge to something less then 0.38.

Confirmation of the result or a correct answer to the problem will be appreciated. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the ellipsis means in your question. It seems that the *a* just above it is the final denominator.

Comment: This is usual notation in (infinite) nested radicals to express that the structure repeats  with the same pattern with infinite terms.

Comment: Yes, but usually that's used where there's a repeat. Should it be at the top?

Answer (score 2):

As it stands the recurrence is
\begin{eqnarray*}
A_n= \sqrt[m]{ \frac{A_{n-1}}{a}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now assuming a limit $A$ exist then gives $A^m a=A$, assume $A=a^{\alpha}$ then $ \alpha=1/(1-m)$ and we have the solution
\begin{eqnarray*}
A= a^{\frac{1}{1-m}}
\end{eqnarray*}
So in your example $a=128, m=6$ does indeed give $A=0.378929 \cdots$.

Not sure what the recurrence would need to be in order to get the solution suggested by the author.

Comment: In my development, trying to unpeel this infinite onion, I got exactly the result $A=a^\frac{1}{1-m}$ you arrived using a clever argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For $m>1$, $a>0$ and $x_0>0$, the recurrence $x_{n+1}=\frac a{\sqrt [m]{x_n}} $
has limit $\ell $ satisfying
$\ell=\frac {\sqrt [m]{\ell}}a $
from which $\ell=a^{\frac m {1+m} }$.
Hence for $a=128$ and $m=6$ you get the limit $\ell=64$.

Comment: I believe that the recurrence is not $x_{n+1}=\frac{\sqrt[m]{x_n}}{a}$ as you are suggesting but  $x_{n+1}=\sqrt[m]{\frac{x_n}{a}}$, as proposed in Donald Splutterwit message.

Comment: The limit of this recurrence is closer to the author's answer.

Comment: But $128^{6/(1-6)}=0.00296..$, not close to 64, nor to 0.37.

Comment: I fing a recurrence with the given limit $a^{\frac m{1+m}}$.

Comment: Thanks Fabio. This is a nice insight (+1). I still believe the author had just messed up the original development, which intended to solve the original problem. But your insight leads the solution to another interesting problem, at least for those that like nested radicals, which I believe is: $$\frac{\begin{array}{c}
\vdots\\a
\end{array}}{\sqrt[m]{\frac{a}{\sqrt[m]{\frac{a}{\sqrt[m]{\frac{a}{\sqrt[m]{a}}}}}}}},$$